# How to slide different div top to down with jQuery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to slide first div to last div synchronize with animation.
could you please help me on jquery.

```
$(function() {
    $('#switch').click(function() {
        $('#one').animate({top:$("#three").offset().top}); 


    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prabhuthapa/U6ADe/166/)

Comment: <div id="one" class="square">1</div>
<div id="two" class="square"> 2</div>
<div id="three" class="square"> 3</div>
<div id="four" class="square"> 4</div>
I just want to swap these four dive

Comment: I have updated an answer. Please, check this out. It is short and simple :)

Answer (score 2):

Your first item is not located at the top of the page and you ignore it while calculating positions. There is a little gap - `body` has `margin` equal to `8px`.

I.e., when you calculate position of block 3, you do:

```
$('#one').animate({top:$("#three").offset().top});
```

`$("#three").offset().top` is equal to 108 because 8 of them is margin, 100 of them is a real position. It moves block to `top = 108`, and with margin, it becomes `116` - 8 pixels lower than you need.
Respectively, blocks 2 and 3 move 8 pixels above than you need.

You need to substract the position of first block in order to get a relative position. Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#switch').click(function() {
        $('#one').animate({top:$("#three").offset().top - $("#one").offset().top}); 
        $('#two').animate({bottom:$("#two").offset().top - $("#one").offset().top});
        $('#three').animate({bottom:$("#two").offset().top - $("#one").offset().top});     
    });
});
```

Check [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U6ADe/167/) out.

**Update:**
Anyway, in my opinion, this approach is incorrect. You have HTML blocks which have relative positions. Manipulating with their positions directly is a bad approach. Moreover, it has difficult calculations and you can easily become confused if you have more than 4 items or if you have complex CSS rules.

The best approach is just **swap their positions in DOM**. It is DOM-friendly, CSS-friendly, cross-browser. It is easily readable and maintainable. Let browser do all the work for you! 
With it, you are also able to add any number of items without changing the code.

Check this JS function:

```
$(function() {    
    $('#switch').click(function() {  
        var firstItem = $(".square:first"); // Take the first item
        firstItem.fadeOut('slow', function() { // Hide it. Then...
            firstItem.parent().append(firstItem); // Add it to the end
            firstItem.fadeIn(); // Show it
        });
    });
});
```

[Full example with fading at JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6ADe/169/).

You can also use `slideUp`, `slideDown` functions in order to make it look better.

[Full example with sliding at JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6ADe/170/).

Without animation it would be even shorter:

```
$(function() {    
    $('#switch').click(function() {  
        var firstItem = $(".square:first"); // Take the first item
        firstItem.parent().append(firstItem); // Add it to the end. Profit!
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to little information, I've created a demo four you please try,

**HTML**

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div id="one" class="square">1</div>
    <div id="two" class="square">2</div>
    <div id="three" class="square">3</div>
    <div id="four" class="square">4</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<br />
<button id="switch">switch positions</button>
```

**CSS**

```
#one {
    top:0;
    background:blue;
}
#two {  
    top:50px;
    background:red;
}
#three {
    top:100px;
    background:purple;
}
#four {
    top:150px;
    background:orange;
}
.square {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
#switch{
    position:relative;
    left:150px;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function () {
    $('#switch').click(function () {
        var t = ($('.square').length-1) * $('.square:first').height();
        $('.square:first').animate({
            top: t
        }, function () {
            $('.square:gt(0)').each(function (i, v) {
                var $el = $('.square:eq(' + (i + 1) + ')');
                $el.animate({
                    top: i * $el.height()
                })
            });
            o = $(this).clone();
            $(this).remove();
            o.insertAfter($('.square:last'));
        });
    });
});
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('#switch').click(function () {
        var t = ($('.square').length-1) * $('.square:first').height();
        $('.square:first').animate({
            top: t
        }, function () {
            $('.square:gt(0)').each(function (i, v) {
                var $el = $('.square:eq(' + (i + 1) + ')');
                $el.animate({
                    top: i * $el.height()
                })
            });
            o = $(this).clone();
            $(this).remove();
            o.insertAfter($('.square:last'));
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#one {
    top:0;
    background:blue;
}
#two {  
    top:50px;
    background:red;
}
#three {
    top:100px;
    background:purple;
}
#four {
    top:150px;
    background:orange;
}
.square {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
#switch{
    position:relative;
    left:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div id="one" class="square">1</div>
    <div id="two" class="square">2</div>
    <div id="three" class="square">3</div>
    <div id="four" class="square">4</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<br />
<button id="switch">switch positions</button>
```

You can also try [Swap Plugin](http://biostall.com/swap-and-re-order-divs-smoothly-using-jquery-swapsie-plugin).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. i appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome... But, I'll be happy if it will fulfill your requirement and my code is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for but I think below is what you are trying to do:

***Snippet:***

```js
$(function() {
    var squares = $('.square');
    var numSquares = squares.length;
    var currPositions = [];
    squares.each(function(index){
        currPositions[index] = $(this).offset().top;
        $(this).data('iterator', index);
    });
    $('#switch').click(function() {
        squares.each(function(index){
            $(this).data('iterator', parseInt($(this).data('iterator')) - 1);
            if (parseInt($(this).data('iterator')) < 0) $(this).data('iterator', numSquares - 1);
            $(this).animate({ top: currPositions[$(this).data('iterator')] });
        });
    });
});
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#one {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
}
#two {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
#three {
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:purple;
}
#four {
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
}
.square {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
#switch {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="square">1</div>
<div id="two" class="square"> 2</div>
<div id="three" class="square"> 3</div>
<div id="four" class="square"> 4</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<br />
<button id="switch">switch positions</button>
```

Hope this helps.

***Details:***

- For this solution to work, I have used `position: absolute;` in CSS for all the `.square` elements i.e. on `#one`, `#two`, `#three` and `#four` elements.
- I have also applied `top` values with an increment of `50px` on each of those elements. The value `50px` comes from taking the `height` of boxes into account.
- In JavaScript, the default positions are first calculated and put inside a `currPositions` array respective of their `index` values.
- Then there is this `$(this).data(...)` helper method of jQuery used to place an `iterator` inside of each of the `.square` jQuery objects.
- This `iterator` is then used to decrement one by one on every element and it keeps iterating through the `currPositions` array previously created, to get the destination values for any current `.square` element to animate to.

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you so much!, i am exactly looking the same result  @Tahir Ahmed

Comment: glad it helped. added **Details** above for further information.